# how to ensure completeness of Swagger documentation in spring project.

Tags: validation, documentation, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger for documentation in my spring project for Rest. 
Is there a way to check completeness of this documentation when a new code or end point is introduced ?

Comment: Personally I'm always in favor for automating instead of manually validating. If you configure Swagger to pick _all_ your controllers up (which you can easily do with Springfox, for example), you can always be sure all of the endpoints are discoverable, no matter how they are introduced in the code. Bear in mind, however, that in may real-world scenarios, you wouldn't want _all_ of your controllers to be listed in Swagger.